# money changing problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, combinatorial-proofs

Given $M\geq 1$ coins of denominations $a_1, \ldots, a_M$, I want to determine the number of ways to make change to obtain a value of $n\geq 0$ coins. We will assume that we have an unrestricted number of coins of each denomination.

For example, if I have only pennies and nickels, the number of ways to obtain $10$ cents is 3 (two nickels, a nickel and five pennies, or 10 pennies).

Now say I only have one kind of coin and its denomination is $a_1$. Then with my unlimited number of coins I can only form change that consists of multiples of $a_1$. I can easily create a generating function whose coefficients tell us the number of ways to make change for $a_1k$ coins for all $k \geq 0$, namely
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (x^{a_1})^k=\frac{1}{1-x^{a_1}}.$$
All the coefficients are $1$ because there is only one way to make change for $a_1k$ if I only have coins of denomination $a_1$.

Now what I am trying to determine is the generating function whose coefficients give me the number of ways to make change for $n$ when I have more than one denomination. I believe that the answer is
$$\prod_{i=1}^M\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty (x^{a_i})^k \right)=\prod_{i=1}^M \frac{1}{1-x^{a_i}}, $$
but I do not know how to prove this. Could someone provide some insight or reference a good proof? Thank you!

Comment: I think your generating function is right. (used the M=3 case once for something and that generating function gave the right values)

Comment: Your intuition is correct. Moreover, if you had a limited supply of coins $a_i$, say you had $n_i$ such coins, then you need only truncate the sum, yielding

$$\prod_{i=1}^M\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n_i} (x^{a_i})^k \right)=\prod_{i=1}^M \frac{1-x^{a_i\cdot(n_i+1)}}{1-x^{a_i}} $$

To be honest, I don't quite know where your doubt lies, because you seem to understand pretty well what happens with $M=1$. I suggest you try and convience yourself that your formula works for $M=2$. I believe if you do that, $M\geq 2$ will follow suit.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri. Thank you for your comment. What I want to know is how to make a combinatorial argument for even the small case like M=2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a quick intermediate step that may help you out.  Let $c_n$ be the number of ways to make change with $a_1,\ldots,a_M$ for $n$.  Then we have $$\sum_{n \geq 0} c_n x^n = \sum_{k_1,k_2,\ldots, k_M} x^{k_1 a_1 + \cdots + k_M a_m} = \prod_{i=1}^M \left( \sum_{k_i = 0}^\infty  x^{k_i a_i}\right) = \prod_{i = 1}^M \frac{1}{1 - x^{a_i}}\,.$$